# C Mysql Connection handler

Tags: mysql, c

I'm trying to connect a C program to Mysql.

I have this code in the main section (I have included the mysql.h header)

```
MYSQL     *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW  row;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    conn = my_init();
    mysqll_real_connect(conn,"localhost","user","pass","database",0,NULL,0);
```

And I have a function outside main that calls that Connection

```
mysql_query(conn,"show tables");
    res = mysql_store_result(conn);
    while ( row = mysql_fetch_row(res) )
    {
            fprintf (stdout,"%s\n", row[0]);
    }
    fprintf (stdout,"\n%lu rows affected\n", (unsigned long) 
    mysql_num_rows(res));
```

The problem is When I compile the code this way

```
gcc -D__DEBUG__=0 -Wall test.c -lmysql -o  test $(mysql_config --libs --include --cflags)
```

I get this messages

```
test.c:162:14: error: ‘conn’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:162:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once     
for each function it appears in
test.c:163:6: error: ‘res’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:164:10: error: ‘row’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

So, I can I do to have only one connection and reuse it inside another function ?

On the main exit I do a mysql_close(conn);

Thanks

Comment: The variables conn, res and row are correctly defined ? are they global ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make common header file and include this file in test.c: Example

```
#ifndef _MAIN_H
#define _MAIN_H 1
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
extern MYSQL     *conn;
extern MYSQL_RES *res;
extern MYSQL_ROW  row;
#endif
```